# Minimum Moves (Grid Path)

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

How can i find the number of minimum moves for a given path with nxn grid to bring both players at each end together on any node?

Below example is for 6x6 grid and each player can move only within given direction. So for the first direction lets say if we move "left" only green can move left and then if we move "up" both red and green can move up and so on. Can we find the minimum number of moves required to move each circle to the same node? What could be the type of algorithm that I should be searching for (shortest path, longest path etc.)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't begin to understand this. Why did the two dots make the moves shown?

Comment: @almagest I think I follow the question, but I don't expect there to be an easy solution... probably Hard at least if not NP-Hard.  Imagine if you will that you have a video game controller that splits and connects to both first and second player's input ports, so each button press registers as a button press for both players.  You have in the game two game pieces, one controlled by the first player and the other by the second player (*both of which are controlled by you with the single controller*) and they travel around the maze.  If a game piece tries to move in an invalid direction...

Comment: ... they just bump against the wall, while the second game piece might have successfully moved.  The goal is to have the two pieces occupy the same location at the same time.  The question is, how to find an optimal sequence of moves that lets the game pieces meet, optimal in the sense that it requires the fewest button presses.

Comment: @JMoravitz Interesting Many thanks. So in the diagram a single downward move at the start would be the minimal solution?

Comment: My interpretation of the given image is that pieces may only move along the black lines, i.e. the two pieces begin at opposite ends of a twisted corridor style maze.  One possible sequence of moves that lets them meet in this given maze might be something like `UUUULULDLLLDDURDDRUURDRDDD`

Comment: @JMoravitz If that's the case, how are we to interpret the statement, "if we move "up" both red and green can move up".

Comment: @saulspatz after the initial movement of `L` in which green moved and red bumped against the wall, green having ended in the sixth row fifth column square while red remains at the initial position of fifth row sixth column square, both red and green now have the ability to simultaneously move `U`, neither of which bouncing against a wall, ending with green at fifth row fifth column and red at fourth row sixth column.  You could do another `U` after in which case green bumps against the wall but red continues making progress up, and so on...

Comment: @JMoravitz I get it now, thanks.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for the clear explanation. It's kind of finding the optimum movement pattern with a single controller. If the question is well understood any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a job for dynamic programming.  This means that we do the problem backwards in a sense.  In any case where both players can move in the same direction, we obviously want to move in that direction.  When we have a choice of two directions to move, we want to move in the direction that leaves the position requiring fewer steps.

Therefore, we start by computing the minimum number of steps required to move from positions where the players are close together, and keep track of the results.  Then we increase the distance by $1$, and use the saved values to compute the new move requirements.

We can modify this to keep track of what the best move is in each case.

I wrote the following python script to do this.

```
green = 'XLULDLLLURRUURDRUULLLDDLUUURRRRRDDDDY'
table = green.maketrans('LRUD', 'RLDU')
red = green.translate(table)
N = len(green)
distance = { }
step = { }

for n in range(N):
    distance[n,n] = 0
for k in range(1, N):
    for n in range(N-k):
        if green[n+1] == red[n+k-1]:
            distance[n,n+k] = 1 + distance[n+1,n+k-1]
            step[n,n+k] = green[n+1]
        elif distance[n,n+k-1] <= distance[n+1,n+k]:
            distance[n,n+k] = 1 + distance[n,n+k-1]
            step[n,n+k] = red[n+k-1]
        else:
            distance[n,n+k] = 1 + distance[n+1,n+k]
            step[n,n+k] = green[n+1]

print(f'{distance[0,N-1]} steps required')
G = 0
R = N-1
steps = ''
while G < R:
    s = step[G,R]
    steps += s
    if s == green[G+1]:
        G += 1
    if s == red[R-1]:
        R  -= 1
print(steps)
```

In the green path, X and Y are just placeholders for the starting positions, and U,D,L,R are the moves needed to get to that cell.  The red path is the same as the green, with the directions reversed.

The program produces the following output:

```
26 steps required
UUUULULDLLLDDDRUURRUURDDLU
```

So, if I haven't made any mistakes, $26$ steps are required, the first $4$ of which are "up", and so on.

I haven't checked this script carefully at all.  You should probably make some small cases that you can solve by hand, and test the script on them.  Let me know of any problems, please.

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm that works is breadth first search. The state space consists of ordered quadruplets $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)$, where $(x_1,y_1)$ are the coordinates of the first piece and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinates of the second piece. The program would maintain

- a queue of states, initially only containing the initial state,
- a set of visited states, initially containing the initial state,
- a dictionary which records the how each state was reached, initially with no entries.

It then repeatedly dequeues a state $s$ from the queue, adds $s$ to the set of visited states, and then enqueues the four states reachable from $s$ attained by pressing up, down, left and right *which have not already been visited*. This is where specifics of the maze have to be used; if there is a wall to the right of $(x_1,y_1)$, then $x_1$ is not increased by pressing right, but otherwise, pressing right increases $x_1$ by one. This continues until a state where $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$ is dequeued.

Furthermore, for each state $t$ added to the queue, a dictionary entry with key $t$ and value $s$ is added to the dictionary. That way, when the algorithm stops, you can backtrack from the final state to find the path which led to it. That is, if the final state is $f_0$, use the dictionary to find the state $f_1$ which lead to it, then the state $f_2$ which led to $f_1$, and so on until you get back to the start state. By using a queue, it is ensured that the resulting path is indeed the shortest path.